# Need help changing if else statements into switch case

Tags: arduino, switch-statement, arduino-uno

So i need help changing the if else statements into switch case statements as i'm new to coding in arduino and can't seem to get it to work. The program is supposed to blink the LED, sound the speaker, light up the bulb, spin the fan and also display the selected message onto the 16x2 lCD when the conditions in the if else statements are fufilled.

```
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

    //Pins of LCD     RS  E  D4 D5  D6 D7
    LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12); // Pins of Arduino 
    int tempPin = A0; //LM35 Pin
    int ldrPin = A1;  //LDR Pin
    int led = 6;    //LED Pin
    int tempMax = 100;
    int buzzer = 13;
    float temp;
    float tempC; 
    int lightReading; 
    int numTones = 2;
    int tones[] = {440, 349};
    int TIP120pin = 5;
    int bulb = A2;

    void setup()
    {
      lcd.begin(16, 2);

      Serial.begin(9600);

      pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

      pinMode(tempPin, INPUT);

      pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);

      pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT); 

      pinMode(TIP120pin, OUTPUT);

      pinMode(bulb, OUTPUT);

      lcd.clear();
      beep(100);
    }
    void loop()
    {
      tempC = (5.0 * analogRead(tempPin) * 100.0) / 1024;
      temp = tempC;
      lightReading = analogRead(ldrPin);

        lcd.print("TEMP:");
        lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
        lcd.print(temp);      // display the temperature
        lcd.print("C");

        // Display Light on second row
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Light           ");
        lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
        lcd.print(lightReading);
        delay(500);
        analogWrite(TIP120pin, 0);
        analogWrite(bulb, 0);

      if (temp >=35)  // if temp is higher than max temp
      {
       lcd.clear();
       analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
       lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
        lcd.print("Room Hot!!");
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        beep(50);
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        delay(200);
      }

      else if (temp >=30 && temp<35)
      {
        lcd.clear();
        analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        beep(50);
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        delay(200); 
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
        lcd.print("Room Warm!");
        delay(200);

      }
     else if (lightReading >100 && lightReading <= 200)
      {
        lcd.clear();
        analogWrite(bulb, 150);
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        beep(50);
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        delay(200); 
        // Display Light on second row
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
        lcd.print("Room Dim");
        delay(200);
        analogWrite(TIP120pin, 0);
      }
      else if (lightReading <=100)
      {
        lcd.clear();
        analogWrite(bulb, 255);
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        beep(50);
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        delay(200);
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
        lcd.print("Room Dark");
        delay(200);
        analogWrite(TIP120pin, 0);
      }    

      else if(temp>=35 && lightReading>100 && lightReading<=200)
      {
        lcd.clear();
        analogWrite(bulb, 150);
        analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        beep(50);
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        delay(200);
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
        lcd.print("Room Hot!");
        lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
        lcd.print("Room Dim!");
        delay(200);
      }

      else if(temp>=35 && lightReading<=100)
      {
        lcd.clear();
        analogWrite(bulb, 255);
        analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        beep(50);
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        delay(200);
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
        lcd.print("Room Hot!");
        lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
        lcd.print("Room Dark!");
        delay(200);
      }

      else if(temp>=30 && temp<35 && lightReading>=100 && lightReading <=200)
      {
        lcd.clear();
        analogWrite(bulb, 150);
        analogWrite(TIP120pin, 150);
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        beep(50);
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        delay(200);
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
        lcd.print("Room Warm!");
        lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
        lcd.print("Room Dim!");
        delay(200);
      }

      else if (temp>=30 && temp<35 && lightReading<100)
      {
        lcd.clear();
        analogWrite(bulb, 255);
        analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        beep(50);
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        delay(200);
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
        lcd.print("Room Hot!!");
        lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
        lcd.print("Room Dark!");
        delay(200);
      }

      else  
      {
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
        analogWrite(bulb, LOW);
        lcd.print("TEMP:");
        lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
        lcd.print(temp);      
        lcd.print("C");

        // Display Light on second row
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Light           ");
        lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
        lcd.print(lightReading);
      }
      delay(500);
      lcd.clear();
      Serial.print("Light,   "); Serial.print(lightReading); Serial.print('\n');
    }
    void beep(unsigned char delayms){
      for(int x=0; x<numTones; x++)
        {
        tone(buzzer, tones[x]);
        delay(delayms);
        }
      noTone(buzzer);  
      }
```

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 I tried implementing the switch case with 2 of the first if else statements and it just displays the  the lightReading and temp without refreshing to show the messages when the conditions were fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to convert if statement to Switch ,i.e i am assuming that you want to improve the readability of the code ,you can use if statement in loop and put switch in a function ..check the code below

```
void loop()
{
  tempC = (5.0 * analogRead(tempPin) * 100.0) / 1024;
  temp = tempC;
  lightReading = analogRead(ldrPin);

    lcd.print("TEMP:");
    lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
    lcd.print(temp);      // display the temperature
    lcd.print("C");

    // Display Light on second row
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Light           ");
    lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
    lcd.print(lightReading);
    delay(500);
    analogWrite(TIP120pin, 0);
    analogWrite(bulb, 0);

  if (temp >=35)  // if temp is higher than max temp
  {
   doSomething('a');
  }

  else if (temp >=30 && temp<35)
  {
  doSomething('b');
  }
 else if (lightReading >100 && lightReading <= 200)
  {
  doSomething('c');
  }
  else if (lightReading <=100)
  {
    doSomething('d');
  }    

  else if(temp>=35 && lightReading>100 && lightReading<=200)
  {
    doSomething('e');
  }

  else if(temp>=35 && lightReading<=100)
  {
    doSomething('f');
  }

  else if(temp>=30 && temp<35 && lightReading>=100 && lightReading <=200)
  {
    doSomething('g');
  }

  else if (temp>=30 && temp<35 && lightReading<100)
  {
    doSomething('h');
  }

  else  
  {
      doSomething('i');
  }
```

and put your different condition in the switch statement in the doSomething() function like this

```
void doSomething(condition){
switch(condition){    
case 'a' :  // if temp is higher than max temp

 lcd.clear();
 analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
 lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  lcd.print("Room Hot!!");
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(50);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
break;

case 'b' :

  lcd.clear();
  analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(50);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200); 
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  lcd.print("Room Warm!");
  delay(200);
break;

case 'c' :
  lcd.clear();
  analogWrite(bulb, 150);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(50);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200); 
  // Display Light on second row
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
  lcd.print("Room Dim");
  delay(200);
  analogWrite(TIP120pin, 0);
break;

case 'd':

  lcd.clear();
  analogWrite(bulb, 255);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(50);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
  lcd.print("Room Dark");
  delay(200);
  analogWrite(TIP120pin, 0);
break;    

case 'e':

  lcd.clear();
  analogWrite(bulb, 150);
  analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(50);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
  lcd.print("Room Hot!");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("Room Dim!");
  delay(200);
break;

case 'f':
  lcd.clear();
  analogWrite(bulb, 255);
  analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(50);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
  lcd.print("Room Hot!");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("Room Dark!");
  delay(200);
break;

case 'g':
  lcd.clear();
  analogWrite(bulb, 150);
  analogWrite(TIP120pin, 150);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(50);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
  lcd.print("Room Warm!");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("Room Dim!");
  delay(200);
break;

case 'h':
  lcd.clear();
  analogWrite(bulb, 255);
  analogWrite(TIP120pin, 255);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(50);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0);  
  lcd.print("Room Hot!!");
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print("Room Dark!");
  delay(200);
break;


default:
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  analogWrite(bulb, LOW);
  lcd.print("TEMP:");
  lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
  lcd.print(temp);      
  lcd.print("C");

  // Display Light on second row
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Light           ");
  lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
  lcd.print(lightReading);
break; 
}
}
```

Comment: I uploaded this code into the arduino and for the conditions where the light and temp were fulfilled, it only showed me either one on the LCD or it just cycles between showing me "Room Warm" and "Room Dark" although I have set it to display on 2 different lines of the LCD.. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Do one thing ..use Serial.println() in all the cases ..and check if u are landing in that condition or not ..

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the switch statement takes this form:

```
switch (expression)
{ 
  case constant:
        statements;
        break;
  [ case constant-2:
        statements;
        break;  ] ...
  [ default:
        statements;
        break;  ] ...
}
```

The switch statement works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types, the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer.

Your nested ifs with their boolean expressions are not a good fit for switch.